# Xamarin AAR library use sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm making bindings for android aar library that has

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

In Native Android project I need to also specify this Java version on 'app' module but where I could do it in Xamarin project?

Comment: Just ensure you have JDK 1.8 installed and your `Diagnostic Build Output` shows it being picked up.

Comment: @JonDouglas The issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532610/is-java-8-features-available-for-xamarin-android-in-java-binding-project). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @TuyếnVũ There are suggestions on that post, have you tried them?

Comment: @JonDouglas Yes, I tried, but non works. My dev machine has JDK 1.8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532610/is-java-8-features-available-for-xamarin-android-in-java-binding-project).

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
  </PropertyGroup>
```