# Is Java 8 features available for Xamarin.Android in Java binding project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an android library project that uses Java 8 features, i.e. via

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

When binding the output AAR to Xamarin.Android, the binding project compiles fine.
However, when trying to use the binding project in a Xamarin.Android application project, I am getting the following error:

```
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
2>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
2>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:615)
2>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:368)
2>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:289)
2>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
2>      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)
2>  Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
2>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
2>      ... 4 more
2>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2096,3): error : java.lang.RuntimeException :  Translation has been interrupted
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

With some googling, it seems to be related to Java 8 feature. I do use a number of new Java 8 features in the native android library. Is this not supported on Xamarin.Android yet?

I did check my Xamarin Diagnostics output, which shows it is using Java 8 to compile:

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_8541cfce\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161).
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's your minSdkVersion?

Comment: Not all features of Java 1.8 are available for all versions of Android.  Some of them require a minSDK of 26.  It looks like you're trying to use some of those.  You'll either need to remove that code, up your minimum SDK, or rewrite it in a way that doesn't use that feature

Comment: I only use the ones listed as "Any" listed here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html. My minSdkVersion is 16.

Comment: Also want to add that this native library works fine in native android application with minSdkVersion of 16. It only has trouble with binding in Xamarin.

Comment: This is still actively being worked on as it was recently merged. See the following pull requests for `desugar` support: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/991 and https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1184 What you are describing is a process called `desugar` that you can read up [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)

Comment: @JonDouglas Thank you very much for your reply! I was wondering if there is any estimated release date for this? Thanks!

Comment: Since it's merged already, I would guess in our 15.6 previews. You should be able to download a master version of Xamarin.Android from the open source repository and use it today. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android#downloads

Comment: @JonDouglas Sorry to bother you again, is there anything I need to do other than installing the patch? After installing "Commercial Xamarin.Android 8.2.99 (master)" patch, I am still getting the same error. In the about dialog, Xamarin.Android SDK version says "8.2.99.5 (HEAD/585344d2a)". Thank you!

Comment: Try to enable via `$(AndroidEnableDesugar)` included in your .csproj.

Comment: EX: `<AndroidEnableDesugar>true</AndroidEnableDesugar>`

Comment: @JonDouglas I am now getting a new error:

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53) 
on a class that presents in the AAR's jar file. Do you have any hint? Thank you!

Comment: I have two binding project each has one AAR library, and one depends on the other, the application, depends on both, could that be a problem?

Comment: Could it be related to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60336? i.e. lambda expression is not supported? Thanks! @JonDouglas

Comment: Also, adding `<AndroidEnableDesugar>true</AndroidEnableDesugar>` to the application project will cause the app to crash on start. Tested with a default blank app and adding this flag to the project file. With error `Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" on path`

Comment: Just an update, I changed my library project back to Java 7 now and everything works fine.

Comment: having same error. Can you recommend other option. Cnnot got below C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161

Comment: Hi @ShirleyG, could you explain more about your way of changing back to Java 7?

Comment: @TuyếnVũ it simply means I reverted my Java project to use Java 7 instead (removing all Java 8 specific features)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the latest Visual Studio 2019 Preview 2.2 and add `<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>` into the csproj of your android project, one for each Debug/Release build

D8 is the new dexer made by google and it enable Desugar mode by default.

Comment: You're my savior! Thank you so so much!