# Xamarin.Android binding generation giving "Type X was not found" errors for classes new in JDK 1.8

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to get Xamarin.Android to generate bindings for a library supplied as an AAR.  JAR2XML is giving me a lot of "can't find type" errors, so I thought I'd try class-parse, but in addition to some library references I'm trying to track down, I'm getting a couple of these:

```
1>  Error while processing '[Method] java.time.temporal.Temporal adjustInto(java.time.temporal.Temporal temporal, long newValue)' in '[Class] java.time.temporal.ChronoField': Type 'java.time.temporal.Temporal' was not found. (TaskId:69)
1>  Error while processing '[Method] java.time.temporal.Temporal addTo(java.time.temporal.Temporal temporal, long amount)' in '[Class] java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit': Type 'java.time.temporal.Temporal' was not found. (TaskId:69)
```

Now, `java.time.temporal.Temporal` is a new type in JDK 1.8, so I'm wondering if maybe that's part of my problem here (ie. maybe the types that can't load are using other new-in-1.8 types).  Running `bin\javac -version` in the path specified in Options-Xamarin-Android Settings says I'm using "1.8.0_172".  My project is targeting "Android 8.1 (Oreo)" - ie. api level 27. Is there some other option I need to set to make sure I'm using 1.8?

Comment: [Java 8 language features need to be `desugared` in Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532610/is-java-8-features-available-for-xamarin-android-in-java-binding-project for how to enable in Xamarin.Android

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation - @jonathan rupp, did you get to work - what did you do exactly?

Comment: @PeterKerr - it was an low-priority project, and something else came up and I never got back to this.  I think someone else took it over a few months later and ended up not trying to bind to that library and used a different one that already had Xamarin bindings.  Sorry I can't help you much :(

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. @JonDouglas can you explain further, or anyone else. I'm using microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25

Comment: @PeterKerr Enable `d8` in your application which will automatically desugar.

Comment: @JonDouglas I upgraded to VS2019 Preview 5, added <AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool> to the .csproj of my Xamain.Binding project, but I still get the same list of errors